# L4D2: Listen (local) server vs Dedicated server

Tags: hosting, networking, left-4-dead-2

So I've been trying for more than two weeks to run a L4D2 Dedicated Server.

However, no one but me can connect to it. I did port forwarding, enabled DMZ and allowed from port 26900 to 27050 on my firewall.

Now, this is an issue I've seen here and in AlliedModders' forums. [Even I posted about it](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=2783640), and at some point managed to fix it by adding

```
sv_allow_lobby_connect_only 0
sm_cvar sv_hibernate_when_empty 0
```

to my server.cfg file, [but then the issue came back out of nowhere](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=338904) and it appears I'm in Carrier-Grade NAT. I still wonder how I managed to bypass it.

Now to the main question, **why is a local server hosted through the game joinable by others, but a dedicated server isn't, when in both cases CGNAT is present?**

Comment: I can't tell if the problem is caused by L4D or not, but you might want to ask over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), as well.

Comment: @Joachim Did you mean [su]? There's no programming going on here, so this would be off-topic on [so]

Comment: [Done](https://superuser.com/q/1735639), got the wrong url lolol